# React Redux - How to take use on a particular location when they come back on that page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am completely new in React/Redux. Currently, I am working on a React/Redux project.

There is a requirement.

> When user browse from one page to another and whenever the user come back on
>   previous page by browser back button, page location(scrollY) should be
>   there from where they left.

I am sorry, I can't share any code because of NDA

Can anyone please guide me the best way to achieve this with React/Redux?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `scroll-restoration` -

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration

react-router v4 comes with it.

Here is the code from react-router docs -

```
class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <App/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)

// or just render it bare anywhere you want, but just one :)
<ScrollToTop/>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I also found this -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-restore-scroll

It is by one of the guys who wrote react-router but it is not actively maintained on [github](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-router-relative-links). But give it a shot.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a similar question -

[How do people handle scroll restoration with react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970279/how-do-people-handle-scroll-restoration-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/), it provides this functionality out of the box.

**EDIT:** it appears that browsers are now beginning to support this natively when `history.pushState` is used (which is what `react-router` uses), so if you just follow the [basic](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) tutorial, it should work for your case.

Comment: Thanks quidproquo. Can you please guide me with bit more details. Sorry about that.

Comment: One more curiosity. Do we need to store the scrollY position on redux state? I mean is that an option? - Thanks

Comment: yes, I suppose you could store the `scrollY` position in the redux state, and then on a connected component you could scroll to that position on `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment so here you go [react-redux-idle-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-idle-monitor)