# Navigate to new page in React without losing data on current page

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-navigation

I have done some digging on this and I have also queried chat-gpt (lol) but I cannot seem to find any resources that tackle the problem. What I am trying to do is simple: on page A, I load a list of 100 items from my server; I can click into each item which would enable me navigate to a new detailed page for that item. When I click the back button, I do not want to have to load all 100 items again, lose my scroll position etc etc.

I know I can maintain state for my scroll position and just `scrollTo()` in my useEffect, but it gets a little trickier for the actual data because I don't want to have to store data for my list of 100 items (could be a lot more than a 100 in production).

Is there a way to neatly do this in react? I currently navigate using the `useNavigate()` hook.

**EDIT--**
I need to state something that makes this a real problem. Page A is paginated in batches of 10. There is a 'more' button I click which loads the next 10 items from the server. So let's say I click into element number 50. When i press the back button, I would like to come back to that element. The useEffect will make it so that it's only the first 10 elements which are loaded again

Comment: navigate as a new tab? if navigate in one tab, it is hard to do like this, may be have to use hack way.

Comment: new tab. Yes I'm realizing I will need to hack it

Comment: The solution varies a lot depending on what router and navigation logic you're using. When a link is clicked are you performing a page refresh (caching will help), or are you doing a synthetic client-side transition (router-specific settings will help)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your data in context using useContext hook. That way you can fetch your data the first time your page loads and save it in an array.

```
import { createContext} from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("jwt_token") ? true : false
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;

export { AuthConsumer, AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

You need to wrap BrowserRouter in App.js:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider> // add the context you want to use
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>

);
);
```

The other approach would be to use Redux or Mobx and using the same logic to check if data is already fetched or needs to be fetched and stored in storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in my work, in that situation I used the "react-query" method from "react-query", which stores all the data loaded from the server in the cache, so when you come back to the previous page we just get the data from cache.

Link: [react query npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query?activeTab=readme)

I don't know whether it works for you or not, just sharing my thought.

Comment: Do you have some simple navigation code you can share?

Comment: Please refer to this article [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-query-fetch-manage-data)

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the recently fetched items using an appropriate caching mechanism (e.g., local storage, session storage, or even in-memory caching) so that they are available when navigating back

For scroll

Answer (score 0):

You are working with react, so i guess you have an idea of Context (useContext),
if yes then you can store data in your context and can use as initial data
whenever you found your list of data in context and yes you can do this same thing for any component or route

and now for your problem of scrolling can be solved by just storing it to your location state by doing following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  scroll to that position on mounting of component
  window.scrollTo = location.state.scrollValue
  return () => {
   // get your scroll position here and store it to
     history.pushState({ scrollValue: / your value to store / })
  }
})
```

or also you can store your score location into context.

```
happy coding
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this thread for scroll restoration [How do people handle scroll restoration with react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970279/how-do-people-handle-scroll-restoration-with-react-router-v4) and as explained above in many answer. Use context or some caching technique to not call network.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use React Router Dom. Each item can be a Route that navigates to a new detailed page for that item.

[enter link description here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route)

Comment: That's currently what I use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution that I will use is to open the item details in a modal then on a new page and worry about caching everything.